# my dependant jars cannot find resources on project classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have a dependancy jar that needs to access files in the resources of the jar as well as the resources of the project I am building that depends on it. I'm not sure if this is a task I need to accomplish or a problem I need to resolve.

Both the jar and the current project that depends on it are mine and I can change either or both. They are both maven and spring based.

More detail:

```
util.jar
 ->Base.class
-resources
 ->base-context.xml

app
 ->App extends Base
-resources
 ->app-context.xml
```

To troubleshoot, I can move app-context into the jars resource folder and everything works as expected. I need to merge the classpaths.

app/src/test/java/com/my/app/App.class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:app-context.xml")
public class App extends Base {...}
```

util.jar

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:util-context.xml")
public abstract class Base extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {...}
```

@contextconfiguration for app.class fails because it cannot locate "classpath:app-context.xml"

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ... 
Caused by:     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [app-context.xml];
```

nested exception is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

This file does exist and is located in the resources folder for the app. If I copy the `app-context.xml` file into the `util.jar` resources folder, the error is resolved, but this workaround is not feasible as a solution.

Comment: What stack trace are you getting and what exactly is your code that fails?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [app-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Please, update the post with the stack trace and, also, post the code that generates the stack trace.

Comment: Confusing. You are saying "I have a dependancy jar that needs to access files in the resources of the jar as well as the resources of the project I am building that depends on it." And judging by the source code, `App` class which belongs to the project tries to access a file which is not in `util.jar`, but in the project itself.

Comment: right, it needs to access resources that are located in both. I'm not claiming that I currently do not have some misconfiguration, but right now app loads util-context.xml just fine, and also loads app.context just fine if I copy it into resource folder of the jar. I don't know why app.jar is not finding things located in the resources folder of the app, but can find resources in the resource folder of the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the paths (case-sensitive!) in the created jars, with 7zip/WinZip or so.

Maybe try

```
classpath:/app-context.xml
```

And `util-context.xml` seems wrong.

Further more maven uses a test/resources directory for test code.

```
app/src/test/java/com/my/app/App.class
app/src/test/resources/app-context.xml
```

Comment: and it turns out someone decided to use resources/app-context.xml and add /resources to the eclipse classpath (which maven knows nothing about). Moving the resources folder to app/src/test/resources was at least 50% of my problem.